# In the morning, I ask somebody "what will you have for lunch?" or "what do you have for lunch?" which one is correct

Tags: tense

In the morning, I ask:

> what will you have for lunch?
>
> what do you have for lunch?

which one is correct?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the circumstances and what you're trying to say? Both are "correct" but have different meanings and different scenarios where they would be appropriate. Is the asker a service staff member at a hotel or restaurant? Is the person being asked packing a lunch for later? Etc.

Comment: Just ask a friend what he wanna eat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

I would probably say "What will you have for lunch?" or "What will you be having for lunch" or "What are you having for lunch?".

"What do you have (with you) for lunch" implies that he is already carrying his lunch with him, and you're just asking what he has.

If I'm buying my friend lunch, I would say: "What would you like for lunch?" or "What do you feel like eating for lunch?" or "What do you want for lunch?".

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct grammar but the meaning is different. In the context of asking a friend about lunch later that day:

> What **will** you have for lunch?

…means that he has already decided what he will eat, and you are asking what his decision was.

> What **do** you have for lunch?

…means that he usually eats the same thing for lunch each day, and you are asking what it is. Or, if your friend brought his lunch with him and hasn't eaten it yet, this question asks what he brought. For the second case, you could also say "What **did you bring** for lunch?" (This is more ordinary.)

If you are going to buy lunch or make lunch later, you say one of these:

> What **would you like** for lunch?
>   What **would you like** to have for lunch?
>   What **would you like** to get for lunch?
>   What **would you like** to eat for lunch?
>   Where **would you like** to go for lunch?  [if lunch will be at a restaurant]
>   What **do you want** for lunch?
>   etc.

These ask your friend to tell you his desire, or to make a decision right now. They do not assume that the decision has already been made.